# 2-PAM or 4-PAM if I want to send data as fast as possible?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, modulation, continuous-signals

I would like to ask if I should use ***2-PAM*** modulation or ***4-PAM*** modulationif I want to send data as fast as possible given that in each case I have the same frequency spectrum available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4-PAM transfers 2 bits ($log_2(4) = 2$) per symbol, while 2-PAM transfers 1 bit per symbol ($log_2(2) = 1$), so 4-PAM definitely transfers data faster.  The catch is that you need higher SNR to get the same bit-error rate (BER) that you would get with 2-PAM.